# getting a C++ std::set's members by index

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to use one of the stl algorithms define in  to get a member of a set using its index position in the set?

I could use a utility method like the one below, but I've got to think this exists already in some generic form in the stl:

```
ElementPtr elementAt(int elementNumber)
{
    list<ElementPtr>::iterator elementIt = elements.begin();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < elementNumber && elementIt != elements.end(); counter++, elementIt++) 
    {
    }

    return *elementIt;
}
```

Comment: Wondering if you could elaborate on your need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iterator>

list<ElementPtr>::iterator elementIt = elements.begin();
std::advance(elementIt, elementNumber);
x = *elementIt;
```

Which does essentially what your code does.

But the fact that you want to do this most likely indicates that you're data structures are wrong. Sets are not designed to be processed like this.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I didn't find advance because it was defined in <iterator> and not <algorithm>.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a usable index mechanism if it's implemented as a binary tree or a hash table, both of which are common for sets.

Comment: `std::set` is implemented as a self-balancing binary tree (red-black in gcc). `std::unordered_set`, from c++0x, uses a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually using the right container type? Consider using a sorted vector instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html) to build both ordering and random access indices on the same underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, as "index-of" doesn't really make sense in terms of a generalized `std::set`.  Unless your set is constructed (and initialized) once and never changed, then you cannot guarantee that the results of calls to the index-of operator would always return a predictable result.

Answer (score 1):

The best you are going to get is an iterator. Sets are containers where the value **is** the index (well, more of a reference in a hash table). Maybe we could better answer your question if we knew what you were trying to do.

I think you are equating a set to an array; they are structured quite differently, a numerical index does not apply.

Comment: `std::set` is typically implemented with a self-balancing binary tree. The hash version is c++0x's `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 0):

You say set, but your code actually indicates list. The two are not the same. Sets are designed to have their elements retrieved by their value. Lists, you can just advance along them using `std::advance`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a numerical index into a set. You need to use a vector instead. And what's more, if you do happen to "get the nth item" in the set, it is not guaranteed it will be there (in the same place) after the set is modified.

Comment: The same applies to a `vector`!